# Specs2 Data Tables with future results

Tags: scala, integration-testing, future, specs2

I'm struggling with following problem:
I have a method that returns a **Future[Result]** where **Result** is the thing I would like to check with a data table row in specs2.

As I understand the following code would block each time and wait for the result to be available.

```
def getDataForInput(input: String) : Future[Result]

def myTest =
 "input"   |  "expectedResult" |>
  "a"    !  123                |
  "b"      !  0                | {
    (input, result) => getDataForInput input must( beEqualTo(result).await )
  }
```

Normally I'd like to make all calls asynchronously and then use **Future.sequence** to transform **Seq[Future[Result]]** to **Future[Seq[Result]]** and then run the tests.

Is there a sane way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *easy* way to do that, you need to deconstruct and reconstruct a few things

```
type RowResult = (Seq[String], Result)

val table =
  "input"  |  "expectedResult" |
   "123"   !  123              |
   "0"     !  1                |
   "0"     !  0

// get a Future containing all rows and results
val results: Future[List[RowResult]] = table.rows.toList.traverseU { row =>
  getDataForInput(row.t1).map { i => 
    (row.showCells, (i must beEqualTo(row.t2)).toResult) 
  }
}

// check the results
results must beSuccessfulTable(table.titles).await
```

This uses a custom matcher which will display the table more less nicely

```
// the TextTable does an even display of columns
import org.specs2.text.TextTable

def beSuccessfulTable(titles: Seq[String]): Matcher[List[RowResult]] = { values: List[RowResult] =>
  val overallSuccess = values.map(_._2).reduce(_ and _).isSuccess
  val headers = if (overallSuccess) titles else Seq("")++titles++Seq("")
  val table = TextTable(headers, values.map(resultLine.tupled))
  (overallSuccess, table.show)
}

// helper method
def resultLine = (line: Seq[String], result: Result) => {
  val message = if (result.isSuccess) "" else result.message
  result.status +: line :+ message
}
```

Comment: I've published new version 3.0.1-20150316014504-0371a05, where you can write `|@ { (input: String, result: Int) => getDataForInput(row.t1).map(_ must beEqualTo(result)) } await`. See the commit [here](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/commit/0371a057f5ebf7364ceb7ecd4eb28247024f9f34).